# Elasticsearch queries and character substitution

Tags: elasticsearch

My Elasticsearch queries are not working properly because sometimes (not always) my stored data have spaces () substituted with underscores (`_`). When users search with spaces, the don't get the entries with underscores in the results.

For example, if users search for the string `annoying problem` they get nothing because `annoying_problem` is the string stored in the index.

I have many similar problems for other characters as well, such as `Ø` being replaced with `o` in the data used to populate my index.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Why sometimes your stored data have spaces and sometimes underscore? Is it on purpose? Do you use a default analyzer? Using this api you can check how inverted index is created: GET /_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=annoying_problem and  GET /_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=annoying problem. I think you need to create your custom analyzer when you will remove underscores - this can be done by setting your own character filter - more information here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html

Comment: @Adam: Thanks, I will look into this. The data I use to populate my index come from many different third party sources. Unfortunately these third parties arbitrarily and wildly replace different characters however they see fit.

Comment: @Gruber I have one suggestion if your data is analyzed. Try a analyzer that tokenizes your data both on basis of space and '_'

Answer (score 1):

try using stopwords

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": { 
          "type": "standard", 
          "stopwords": [ "_"] 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

refrence https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/using-stopwords.html

Comment: If I run this (adding `PUT my_index_name` above your code) I get `index_already_exists_exception`. How can I run this on an existing index?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html